# How to fetch images from database and display it in a Bootstrap 3 thumbnail slider?

Tags: html, mysql, image, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I wanted to use this thumbnail slider from Bootstrap http://www.bootply.com/81478 in my webpage. To get all the images from the database, this is how i fetch and echo them:

```
 <?php while ($rowz = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
 ?><img width="150"src="images/<?php echo $rowz['image']; ?><?php}?>
```

However, the following example from the link I have given above, the images are hardcoded for an example obviously. I tried inserting those lines of codes like this but it gives me multiple sliders with only an image in it. How do I fix this such that all the images that i fetch from the database gets into this slider as one row?

```
<?php while ($rowz = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) { <--fetch by loop-->
 ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12">
     <h1>Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Slider</h1>
    <div class="well">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
<img width="150"src="images/<?php echo $rowz['image']; ?><?php}?> <--echo here-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/row-->
                </div>
```